# How can I use tf.contrib mnist_data_provider?

Tags: tensorflow

Are there any special installation instructions for tf.contrib?
I am trying to follow [enter link description here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/gan) and on the second line

`images = mnist_data_provider.provide_data(FLAGS.batch_size)`

get error

```
NameError: name 'mnist_data_provider' is not defined
```

Using TensorFlow: 1.13.1
Numpy: 1.16.3
Python: 3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

tf.confib is soon going to be outdated and it is recommended to switch to something else. I can recommend using tf.keras.data for that purpose:

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()  # we only need train images here [60000, 28, 28]
# convert that into data provider
dataste = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
```

I think it should work when you provide it to `tfgan.gan_model`